# Adding DataRow one by one to DataTable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, telerik, datarow

I have a webform for entering Invoice info to a DB.

I have 3 textboxes requesting product quantity, product and price.

I decided to create a DataTable to store temporarily quantity, productId, price so that the user might add N products for later saving the data on the DataTable (displayed on a grid) to the DB.

I don't know what am I doing wrong but am unable to store a second product. After I save 1 row to the DataTable the second one is not added but overwrites the first one. I know this has to be something really stupid on my part but haven´t been able to figure out what am I doing wrong and am sort of a beginner.

```
Public Class IngresoFacturas
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim miDataTable = New DataTable

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        miDataTable.Columns.Add("dCantidad", GetType(System.Int32))
        miDataTable.Columns.Add("idProducto", GetType(System.Int32))
        miDataTable.Columns.Add("mTotal", GetType(System.Decimal))

    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton1.Click

        miDataTable.Rows.Add(RadNumericTextBox2.Text, Int32.Parse(RadAutoCompleteBox2.Entries.Item(0).Value), RadNumericTextBox3.Text)
        RadGrid1.Rebind() 'Forces rebind to update Grid
        RadAutoCompleteBox2.Entries.Clear()
        RadNumericTextBox2.Text = ""
        RadNumericTextBox3.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Protected Sub RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.NeedDataSource

        RadGrid1.DataSource = miDataTable

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: WebForms always create a new instance of class, `IngresoFacturas` in your case, on every request. In your code always create a new DataTable on every request.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. Any ideas on how to work around this? Saving yo xml or any other idea??

Answer (score 0):

Tried Andrew´s solution but it didn{t work so I came up to this:

Anything you guys could warn me about using ViewState to solve this. It is working.... but don{t know if it{s the best approach

```
    Public Class IngresoFacturas
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim miDataTable As DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        miDataTable = New DataTable
        miDataTable.Columns.Add("dCantidad", GetType(System.Int32))
        miDataTable.Columns.Add("idProducto", GetType(System.Int32))
        miDataTable.Columns.Add("mTotal", GetType(System.Decimal))
        ViewState("tabla") = miDataTable
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub RadButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton1.Click
    miDataTable = ViewState("tabla")
    miDataTable.Rows.Add(RadNumericTextBox2.Text, Int32.Parse(RadAutoCompleteBox2.Entries.Item(0).Value), RadNumericTextBox3.Text)
    RadGrid1.Rebind() 'Forces rebind to update Grid
    ViewState("tabla") = miDataTable
    RadAutoCompleteBox2.Entries.Clear()
    RadNumericTextBox2.Text = ""
    RadNumericTextBox3.Text = ""

End Sub

Protected Sub RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.NeedDataSource

    RadGrid1.DataSource = miDataTable

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might help:

```
Dim miDataTable As DataTable

Sub PrepareDT()
    miDataTable = New DataTable
    miDataTable.Columns.Add("dCantidad", GetType(System.Int32))
    miDataTable.Columns.Add("idProducto", GetType(System.Int32))
    miDataTable.Columns.Add("mTotal", GetType(System.Decimal))

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        PrepareDT()
    End If

End Sub
```

(and remove the code from the `Page_Load` method) so that you only "reset" miDataTable on the first access of the page.